# ListView not scrolling inside of NestedScrollView

Tags: android, listview, nestedscrollview

I am using a ListView inside of a NestedScrollView. 
The List expand to match the parent but there is no scrolling now

Here is my layout :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true"
>
       <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/workExperienceListLV"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This line did not help :

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use recyclerview, you cannot use nestedscrolling feature with listview.

Comment: @oguzhand Is there any way that i can make it work with a listView ?

Comment: As scroll is available in ListView, you can't use a ScrollView wrapping it. So instead set layout_height to some dp say it 200dp, then layout will scroll. If you use only ListView in that layout, you don't have to put NestedScrollView wrapping it.

Comment: RecyclerView and NestedScrollView designed for working together, ListView is an old widget, doesn't support nested scrolling. You can manage it but your recycle structure will not work(which is illogical). I never use Listview for months. Just use RecyclerView.

Comment: Okay I will switch to RecyclerView thank you! You really helped me.  @oguzhand

Answer (score 0):

Use `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled()` and you should be fine.

Answer (score -3):

this is because of using a  ListView  inside a scrollview(NestedScrollView).becacuse both having scroll ,if you want to scroll this you just reduce the width of the listview to half of the screen. 
like this..

```
 <ListView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/workExperienceListLV"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```